# Keep the the alert box without dismiss if there is an error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is just an alert box with radio buttons. All are working fine except one thing. That is If there is an error I cannot retain the alert box until the user enters the correct data. According to [the doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) I have used `return false` feature. But no luck yet. Any clue?

`Note:` This is working fine if inputs are `text boxes`. Here I need radio buttons.

```
const allApiKeys = await this.apiKeySqliteProvider.getAllApiKeys();
            const alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
            alert.setTitle('Select Api Key');
            forEach(allApiKeys, (apiKey: ApiKey) => {
              alert.addInput({
                type: 'radio',
                label: apiKey.name,
                value: apiKey.key,
                checked: false
              });
            });
            alert.addButton({
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: data => {
                this.loading.dismissLoader(loading);
              }
            });
            alert.addButton({
              text: 'OK',
              handler: data => {
                let navTransition = alert.dismiss();
                navTransition.then(() => {
                 if (data == null) {
                    this.showToastProvider.showErrorToast("Invalid API Key");
                    this.loading.dismissLoader(loading);
                    return false;
                  } 
                });
                return false;
              }
            });
            alert.present();
          }
```

Comment: "return false" is not actual problem. You are calling alert.dismiss, that's the issue. If you don't want to hide alert, you should move dismiss code inside else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return false` is not the actual problem. You are calling `alert.dismiss`, that's the issue. If you don't want to hide alert, you should move `dismiss` code inside `else` block.

Please change your code to following

```
 const allApiKeys = await this.apiKeySqliteProvider.getAllApiKeys();
                const alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
                alert.setTitle('Select Api Key');
                forEach(allApiKeys, (apiKey: ApiKey) => {
                  alert.addInput({
                    type: 'radio',
                    label: apiKey.name,
                    value: apiKey.key,
                    checked: false
                  });
                });
                alert.addButton({
                  text: 'Cancel',
                  role: 'cancel',
                  handler: data => {
                    this.loading.dismissLoader(loading);
                  }
                });
                alert.addButton({
                  text: 'OK',
                  handler: data => {
                      if (data == null) {
                        this.showToastProvider.showErrorToast("Invalid API Key");
                        this.loading.dismissLoader(loading);
                        return false;
                      }

                      // you don't need else here as by default it will hide alert
                  }
                });
                alert.present();
              }
```

Comment: That was a very basic mistake which I have done. Thanks a lot for showing it to me.

Comment: Any time :) glad i helped :)